# Ubuntu 18.04 (Mate) - Meld Freezing

Tags: 18.04, meld

Meld (3.18.0) keeps freezing on me in Ubuntu 18.04 Mate, when I try to compare certain files or perform `git mergetool`. E.g. if I view a diff on one change it may work, but if I try on another it will freeze. If I keep retrying on that change, it will always keep freezing, indicating that it is no random, but dependent on what its comparing.

The only output I have to go on so far is:

```
**
GtkSourceView:ERROR:gtksourcecontextengine.c:5543:update_syntax: assertion failed: (g_slist_length (ce->priv->invalid) <= 1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can't seem to find a --verbose or -v option to get more output to go on.

Does anybody know what the issues is, or how I might be able to better diagnose what is going wrong?

Comment: Please provide real-life example. Is it your private Git-repository or public-available one? Could you please give us a link and list of commands which you have ran?

Comment: Same version (3.18.0) is freezing for me, too.  I'm just comparing two text files, ~4.6k each (very small).

Comment: It seems to just be a performance issue. Whenever there is a large file, or a file that has a lot on just one line (such as minified JS files), then meld has a real issue. I get around this by using vimdiff or tkdiff in such circumstances. I prefer tkdiff but can't figure out how to edit the files in it and will fallback to vimdiff in such circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

**Disable `Preferences`>`Folder Comparison`>`Apply text filters during folder comparisons`**

I just installed `meld` on Ubuntu 18.10 and also had it freeze frequently. I changed the preferences by disabling `Preferences`>`Folder Comparison`>`Apply text filters during folder comparisons`. Obviously that makes directory comparison cheaper. This also may be the reason in your situation as even when diff'ing only small files there may be some folder being auto-compared 'full-text-wise' in the background.

[Meld Preferences: disable `Apply text filters during folder comparisons`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZzGH.png)